# PitchBlackRecoveryProject: Build error: font missing

Tags: android, build, fonts, recovery, samsung

I tried to build PBRP for a Samsung Galaxy A24.

When compiling PBRP, i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Can not find the font file NotoSansEthiopic-Regular for language am
    at com.android.recovery.tools.ImageGenerator.loadFontsByLocale(ImageGenerator.java:399)
    at com.android.recovery.tools.ImageGenerator.createGraphics(ImageGenerator.java:492)
    at com.android.recovery.tools.ImageGenerator.measureTextWidth(ImageGenerator.java:500)
    at com.android.recovery.tools.ImageGenerator.generateImage(ImageGenerator.java:618)
    at com.android.recovery.tools.ImageGenerator.main(ImageGenerator.java:755)
10:05:28 ninja failed with: exit status 1

### failed to build some targets (40:59 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same error, I fixed it by manually downloading the missing font then put it in the right directory, in your case, in `external/noto-fonts/others`. I don't know if there's better way to solve it.

Edited -- 1 :

```
cd external/noto-fonts/other
wget https://github.com/cd-Crypton/custom-recovery-extras/raw/main/missing-font.zip
unzip -o missing-font.zip
cd ../../..
```

This was the method I used. This consists of some missing fonts needed by PBRP.